# Extracting words inside bracket using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

What will be the regular expression for the following pattern shown in the image below? (Note: there are many more tags and in no specific order.there is a lot of information between the tags that dont follow this pattern. i just need to extract the information within the large bracket)[image: Data pattern]

I need to seperate the data inside the large bracket seperately. for e.g. severity and 2. So far, i have only been able to collect the data having such large brackets using `r'\[([^]]*)\]'`. how do i seperate them? and please do explain. I am familiar with regex symbols but cannot work my head around with these complicated patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

rx = re.compile("""\[(?P<key>[^\]\[\s]+)(?:\s+"(?P<value>[^"]+)")?\]""")
text = """lorem ipsum [severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] lorem ipsum"""

result = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(text)}
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
{'severity': '2', 'maturity': '0', 'accuracy': '0', 'tag': 'application-multi'}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WgLEJj/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
value = '[severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"]'
print(re.findall(r'\[(\w+)\s+"([^"]+)"\]', value))
```

This will give you the keys and values: `[('severity', '2'), ('maturity', '0'), ('accuracy', '0'), ('tag', 'application-multi')]`

If you want a dictionary that's easy: `print(dict(re.findall(r'\[(\w+)\s+"([^"]+)"\]', value)))`

Now the explanation of the regular expression.
First looking for an opening bracket: `\[` (escaped). Then catch the word characters: `(\w+)`. Then one or more spaces followed by a double quote: `\s+"`. Then we catch everything that's not a double quote: `([^"]+)`. Finally find the double quote followed by the closing bracket: `"\]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `re.finditer` to loop over matches, and use these to create a dictionary:

```
import re

text = '[severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"]'

tags = {m.group(1): m.group(2)
        for m in re.finditer('\[(.*?)\s*"(.*?)"\]', text)}

print(tags)
```

```
{'severity': '2', 'ver': '', 'maturity': '0', 'accuracy': '0', 'tag': 'application-multi'}
```

This makes it convenient to extract data items, but it does of course assume that keys are unique.  If they are not, then you could instead use for example a list of 2-tuples:

```
[(m.group(1), m.group(2))
 for m in re.finditer('\[(.*?)\s*"(.*?)"\]', text)]
```

```
[('severity', '2'), ('ver', ''), ('maturity', '0'), ('accuracy', '0'), ('tag', 'application-multi')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the first and second word of each pair:

```
>>> import re
>>> inp = '[severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"]'
>>> list_of_tuples = re.findall(r'\[(\w+) \"(.*?)\"\]', inp)
>>> list_of_tuples
[('severity', '2'), ('ver', ''), ('maturity', '0'), ('accuracy', '0'), ('tag', 'application-multi')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\[([^][]+?)(?:\s+"([^"]*)")?]
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/C8YCFs/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^][]+?                  any character except: ']', '[' (1 or
                             more times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##TY/NigIxEITv8xRNLpPorvhzE2QeJEYIY9SGyQ@dzjKy@OxjBhG91dfdVFelO99i2E0T@hSJgVzjxkQuZ4wBDkDtUUt9MtosOyW7/TEvRWVhFkqozrQNu8z1rh0iOQ@YcvGgs/tzhHwHsRUGdAUQs/CWy2u@ntH2fSHbv5HtFYRNacDecn3/68vAWDdf3m2TCANL@B9XV4olyY3av@VWwSUSjIChFlldMJyRHclPox@Y86oHqGaang):

```
import re
expression = r'\[([^][]+?)(?:\s+"([^"]*)")?]'
test = 'lorem ipsum [severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] lorem ipsum'
print( {x.group(1):x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(expression, test)} )
```

Result:

```
{'severity': '2', 'ver': '', 'maturity': '0', 'accuracy': '0', 'tag': 'application-multi'}
```